# .net core. Basic form, but empty string becomes null

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

If we have a 100% basic form, with a input type text, basic route, basic view and controller.

If we submit the empty string, or a string with only blankspaces, it comes into the method in the controller as null.

We find this super weird, we need to be able to receive empty strings.

There is nothing complex in work here, brand new MWC-project. no Model stuff.

Why do we get it in as null. Below I have postet our form, the route, and the method from the controller.

How do we make our controler being able to receive empty string?

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

<form method="POST" action="/Home/ProcessForm">
    <div class="header">MetaIGPageIDDD</div>
    <input type="text" name="input" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

       [HttpPost]
       public IActionResult ProcessForm(string input)
       {
           string ret = "input: |" + input + "| len:" + input.Length;
           //if (MetaIGPageID == "") ret = ret + "empty string, not null";
           //if (MetaIGPageID == null) ret = ret + "Now null 1";
           //if (MetaIGPageID == null) ret = ret + "Now null 2";

           throw new Exception(ret);
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is expected behaviour designed so . Due to various reasons for example make model-validation easy , provide compatibility for data storing , and indicate there is no data and field is left blank. If you want to receive null data as empty , instead of converting the data in controller , you can create custom model-binder.

**EmptyStringModelBinder.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;

namespace StringEmpty
{

    public class EmptyStringModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            if (bindingContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
            }

            var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

            if (valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None)
            {
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }

            bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, valueProviderResult);

            // Use an empty string if the value is null or whitespace
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(valueProviderResult.FirstValue ?? string.Empty);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

**EmptyStringModelBinderProvider.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders;

namespace StringEmpty
{

    public class EmptyStringModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
    {
        public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
            }

            if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(string))
            {
                return new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(EmptyStringModelBinder));
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new EmptyStringModelBinderProvider());
});
```

[image]

Comment: thanks alot!!!!. Se also my post below here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. We also found out that we can use

```
   [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
   public class AllowEmptyAttribute : DisplayFormatAttribute
   {
       public AllowEmptyAttribute() : base() { ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false; }
   }
```

And then just add [AllowEmpty] attribute in the method like

```
public IActionResult SubmitForm([AllowEmpty] string exampleInput)
```

I still find it weird that this should be default, as it also happens with one or more "blank space".

And we found this bug-thread, which indicates that some bug in .NET is also in play here:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/29948

**

Anyway!!. Thanks. For now we use the Atribute solution. But we are still strugling to understand this weird behaviour 100%.